# How can I find when a company went private or delisted or inactive?

Tags: stocks

I am looking around to find when a particular company has stopped trading actively or when it went private in US stock exchanges.  How can I find this information?

Comment: I edited your question to be on topic here; asking for a tool or dataset wouldn't be on topic here, but the way David answered it suggested an on-topic question that I edited it to (how can you find this out in general, which is fine).

Answer (score 1):

[EDGAR](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html) should have what you need for US companies. For example, searching for Rackspace (which went private in 2016) then clicking [CIK 0001107694](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001107694&owner=exclude&count=40&hidefilings=0) will get you all of Rackspace's filings, including the *Definitive proxy statement relating to merger or acquisition* on 2016-09-30 and the last 10-Q on 2016-11-09, and subsequently the *Securities registration termination [Section 12(b)]* on 2016-11-14.

You can search EDGAR by form type, as long as the date you are looking for is after 1994. See [this search](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=COMPANY-NAME%3DRackspace+FORM-TYPE%3D15-12B&first=2016&last=2016) which gets Rackspace's filing, and note that you can also [wildcard the search fields](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=COMPANY-NAME%3DRa*%20FORM-TYPE%3D15-12*&first=2015&last=2018). Note that you're limited to 4000 results returned, so how you search will depend on your data. [This search](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=FORM-TYPE%3D15-12B&first=2008&last=2018) gets all 15-12(b) terminations in the last decade.

You won't get more accurate information for US companies anywhere, and AFAIK you won't get better search capabilities or slice and dice without paying for it.

Comment: thanks for the information,by any chance do we have any source from where we can download all the delisted stocks and their filing dates because i have around 1000  plus  companies in my list for which i am trying to get the delisting dates

Comment: @user31737 I've added some information that should  get you what you want pretty easily, but without knowing what your data looks like, or what your budget is, or how much time you're willing to spend on this, it's difficult to get more specific.